# why after writing with memcpy in a portion of memory mmaped, I don't see in the file?

Tags: c, mmap, memcpy

When I open the file after a run of the program, I saw only the first phrase.

```
void writeInFileMmaped(){

void* file_memory=NULL;
char* path="/home/testFile";
int fdTest=0;
struct stat bufTest;

char *phrase= "Hi, I'm a phrase";

//Make a file with 20M
system("truncate -s 20M /home/testFile");

//Open testFile
if((fdTest=open(path,O_RDWR))==-1){
    perror("open testFile");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(fstat(fdTest,&bufTest)==-1){
    perror("stat");
}

file_memory=mmap(0, bufTest.st_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fdTest,0);

if(file_memory==MAP_FAILED){
    close(fdTest);
    perror("Error mapping the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
memcpy(file_memory,phrase,strlen(phrase));
printf("%sn",file_memory);
memcpy(file_memory+100, phrase,strlen(phrase));
printf("%sn",file_memory+100);
```

}

The output is good, but in the file only appears "Hi, I'm a phrase"
I try with sprintf and the result is the same.
I think is a problem with the NULL

Comment: `system("truncate -s 20M /home/testFile");` makes an empty file (a "file with a hole in it") with size=20M. (it will appear to be filled with binary NULs) Try to use another file (eg a copy of /usr/share/dict) as substrate for your experiment.

Comment: `head -c 150 /home/testFile | xxd`

Comment: I think the code works fine. How have you tried to visualize the content of the file? Try the command given by @FatalError

Comment: Maybe the changes simply weren't written back? If so this is a usecase for `msync()`. `msync(file_memory, 20000000, MS_SYNC)` will force the changes to be written back. As the man-page says, _`msync()`  flushes  changes  made  to  the in-core copy of a file that was mapped into memory using `mmap(2)` back to disk.  Without use of this call there is no guarantee that changes are written back before `munmap(2)` is called.  To be more precise, the part of the file that corresponds to the memory area starting at `addr` and having length `length` is updated._

Comment: You are using arithmetic on a `void*`, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @EOF it's ill-formed (meaning the compiler must complain, and if any executable is generated then the entire program has UB)

Comment: Why use system() when ftruncate works directly?

Comment: wildplasser: With another file it's ok, thank's! It was for that of "binary NULs".

Pynchia: I was trying to open it with Leafpad in Linux, with head -c 150 /home/testFile | xxd

It shows what I wanted

Iwillnotexist Idonotexist: The changes were made, likewise, I will start using it

EOF: with other forms failed, this one not.

@Jeff: I just wanted make a new file with a fixed size, because I need to treat them with blocks later.
And I don't know how create a empty file with a fixed size